# Convert from Watson NLC to NLU

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-nlu, nl-classifier

We are trying to convert from Watson NLC to NLU using the same NLC training csv data.
There are 3 classification models to convert.
Current status of these models are all "error".
2 model messages are
"internal training error occurred, please try again"

1 model message is
"Training data validation failed: Too few examples for label XXXX. Minimum of 5 required"

There are two questions.

1. Does NLC CSV data have to be processed to be usable?
2. What is the best way to deal with these error messages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the API to specify the training data? If so then the API documentation specify the it should be provided as json - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding#createclassificationsmodel